# Is there a way to get a crash report (not a core dump) for a command line program?

Tags: macos, command-line, crash

If a macOS application crashes, CrashReporter will (optionally) pop up a window with a human-readable set of stack traces and the "Send to Apple" button.

Is there a straightforward way to get the same results for a non-`.app` program which crashes when started from the command line? That is, the situation I want more information out of is

```
$ some-program
Segmentation fault: 11
$
```

I've only found instructions about how to enable core dumps, but not how to get something readable out of them. I know that Activity Monitor can "sample" running programs, but I'm looking for the crash event, not profiling.

I've thought of creating a dummy `.app` package that actually runs the command that's crashing, but that'll be a bit of work and probably run into some Gatekeeper trouble, though I haven't actually tried doing that since a few major versions ago. I'm currently on Catalina 10.15.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking back, past crashes are logged in the log system, and also individual dump files are saved for about a month in **/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports**

Looking forward, to cause them is a bit harder and risky. You could try issuing a SIGABRT or SIGQUIT signal if you know the process:

- [How to crash an application to produce Crash Report](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/399138/how-to-crash-an-application-to-produce-crash-report)

Something more generic would be the general system diagnostics will capture  much more. The main difference in these two options is a crash has an end point, system diagnosis grabs an arbitrary snapshot, so it isn’t necessarily as final as a crash. I don’t recommend [forcing an app to crash](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/398383/5472) and [certainly don’t recommend forcing a kernel panic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/315587/5472) but you could try both. Why not start with a general diagnostic dump:

```
sudo sysdiagnose
```

You can pass a process ID or process name to sysdiagnose or also trigger it from the Activity Monitor app.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/activity-monitor/welcome/mac

If you need to halt the program or process, try Instruments from Xcode.

- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12

Comment: In hindsight I didn't quite make it clear enough: I'm not trying to get info from a _running_ program, but one that _did crash_, so "how to crash", Activity Monitor and Instruments are all not relevant. I've edited my question to make the focus clear. • However, I see that sysdiagnose did in fact produce `.crash` files for the commands I wanted to troubleshoot. Do you happen to know if there is a way to get these files that's faster than running the fairly slow `sysdiagnose` command and unarchiving its output?

Comment: @KevinReid Wonderful edits and clarifications. All crashes get deposited in `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` and the. purged roughly after a month.

Comment: Ah, that's perfect! If you could edit your answer to focus on that, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @bmike to clarify, `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` only seems to have crash reports for OS-level components. For user applications, the actual directory is `$HOME/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` instead.